# Why is Hadoop unable to find this file in local mode even though it exists?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs, hadoop-yarn

I am getting this error when running Hadoop in local mode through maven.

```
15/03/24 12:45:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: Map output collector class = org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$MapOutputBuffer

15/03/24 12:45:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: (EQUATOR) 0 kvi 26214396(104857584)
15/03/24 12:45:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: mapreduce.task.io.sort.mb: 100
15/03/24 12:45:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: soft limit at 83886080
15/03/24 12:45:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: bufstart = 0; bufvoid = 104857600
15/03/24 12:45:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: kvstart = 26214396; length = 6553600
15/03/24 12:45:25 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local977124269_0001 running in uber mode : false
15/03/24 12:45:25 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
15/03/24 12:45:26 INFO mapred.MapTask: Starting flush of map output
15/03/24 12:45:26 INFO mapred.LocalJobRunner: Map task executor complete.
15/03/24 12:45:26 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local977124269_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:<home_dir>/src/test/data/doc/<file> (No such file or directory)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:403)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:<home_dir>/src/test/data/doc/<file> (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at package.DocumentRecordReader.parseDocument(DocumentRecordReader.java:186)
    at package.DocumentRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DocumentRecordReader.java:130)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.CombineFileRecordReader.nextKeyValue(CombineFileRecordReader.java:69)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:532)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.task.MapContextImpl.nextKeyValue(MapContextImpl.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.map.WrappedMapper$Context.nextKeyValue(WrappedMapper.java:91)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:763)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:339)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job$MapTaskRunnable.run(LocalJobRunner.java:235)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
15/03/24 12:45:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_local977124269_0001 failed with state FAILED due to: NA
15/03/24 12:45:26 INFO mapreduce.Job: Counters: 0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Command execution failed.
```

As you can see the maven verify goal failed because Hadoop was unable to find the file in the src/test/data/doc directory. I can manually see that the path is correct and the file is indeed present.

Can someone tell me what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 1):

I think file:home_dir is not set in your environment variable.

Comment: Can you please elaborate it a bit? What is the exact variable I need to set please?

Comment: you are running on window or linux. please visit below link for window (http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm)  and  for linux(http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/set-environment-variable-linux/)

Comment: I am running it on Linux and I have all the environment variables set.

Comment: try with absolute path and check.